# Facing Lettuce connection refused issue when running with embedded redis test cases in local is running fine but in jenkins its failing

Tags: java, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I have written redis test cases with embedded redis and its worked fine without any issues in local. But when I moved to CI / CD pipeline with jenkins i am facing connection refused issue.

```
cache.redis.core.BaseRedisDataStructure - Error while getting the element from cache
io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:242)
```

Any idea why its failing in remote and not in local?
I have verified the port openings in that jenkins machine so no port related issues.
Thanks for your Time,

Comment: I got a similar error `Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at Errors.java:124` during running tests on Jenkins pipeline, but locally it's good.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which environment your jenkins pipeline are being executed. Some linux environments doesn't have default host mapping for `localhost`. As a quick fix you can change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`